# AngularJS Service to Service with a delay

Tags: angularjs, html, jquery-ui, angularjs-routing

I am currently facing a problem with my project's design.
I am using angularjs framework and my task is to provide a translations for a webpage, but the translations need to be provided form the xml file o the BE side.
So since I#ve found out that angulars i18n is configurable on the FE side i had to use another strategy.

I've decided to make a service which fetches the data during a resolve period before everything else is loaded:

```
app.factory('dictionaryService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
return {

    getDictionary: function (defaultLanguage) {

        var chosenLanguage = null;
        if (angular.isUndefined($rootScope.defaultLanguage) || $rootScope.defaultLanguage == null) {
            chosenLanguage = defaultLanguage;
            $rootScope.defaultLanguage = chosenLanguage;
        } else {
            chosenLanguage = $rootScope.defaultLanguage;
        }

        var translation = new Array();


        translation[chosenLanguage] = new Array();

        return $http.get('Translation/GetCurrentDictionary/', {
            params: {
                language: chosenLanguage
            }
        });
    },
    GetLanguagesSetup: function () {
        return $http.get('Translation/GetLanguagesSetup/');
    }

}

}]);
```

and then resolve it as follows:

```
    $routeProvider.when("/diagnose", {
    controller: "diagnoseCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/diagnose.html",
    resolve: {
        startupData: function (dictionaryService, $q) {
            var def = $q.defer();
            var translation = new Array();

            var startupData = new Array();
            var defaultLanguage = "EN";

            var dict = dictionaryService.getDictionary(defaultLanguage).then(function (JSONData) {
                var keys = Object.keys(JSONData.data.data);
                var chosenLanguage = JSONData.data.lang;
                translation[chosenLanguage] = {};

                for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    translation[keys[i]] = JSONData.data.data[keys[i]];
                }

                startupData['translations'] = translation;

                def.resolve(startupData);

            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log("Translation fetching exception, " + e);
                return $q.reject(e);
            });




            return def.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

So as you can see I am storing my fetched translations in a startupData. Then in a controller which is using it I am assigning this data to the $rootScope. It seems already here as a not the best solution, but I could not come up with a different one
Then I have created a translation service which gets the direct translation text:

```
app.factory('translationService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {


var translations = null;

return {
    getText: function (key) {
        if ($rootScope.cachedTranslations == undefined) {
            return key;
        }
        var result = $rootScope.cachedTranslations[key];

        if (result == null) {

            return key;
        } else {
            return result;
        }

    }

}

}]);
```

The biggest problem with this solution is, that I am not using promises, but I do not want to make an http query to BE for each translation.
The other problem is with the html template provided by the designers:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController">
<loading-screen ng-show="!isDataLoaded"></loading-screen>

<div id="header" class="headerView" ng-controller="headerController" ng-show="isDataLoaded">
        some header stuff
        ...

        <button ng-bind="option1" ng-click="redirectTo('#subpage1')"></button>
        <button ng-bind="option2" ng-click="redirectTo('#subpage2')"></button>
        <button ng-bind="option3" ng-click="redirectTo('#subpage3')"></button>
        <button ng-bind="language" ng-if="availableLanguages.length > 1" ng-repeat="language in availableLanguages" ng-click="setLanguage(language)"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<
<div id="content" ng-view ng-show="isDataLoaded">
</div>
<footer id="footer" class="footer" ng-show="isDataLoaded">
    <status-bar></status-bar>
</footer>
```

Resolve applies only for ng-views's controller, but header stuff needs to be translated as well, so I need to make a headerCtrl somehow wait before it tries to apply translations.
So I have made another unpopular decision to inform all controllers about the finished startup via a broadcast message and to wait until it is all done while showing the loading screen.
It looks fine and is pretty responsive (1sec per startup is acceptable at this point).

The problem is, that I see many design mistakes with this attempt and I just can not come up with the better design.

So my main question is:
**How can I make it better? 1st service returns a whole array which is used by the 2nd service so I do not know how to combine it with promises?**
**I am afraid that with the development of the application I will find myself in a global variables and global events hell**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You seem to be developing your own i18n solution for angular. Any reason one of the existing ones like https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate will not do the job?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for comment! Unfortunately angular-translate requires a $translateProvider to deliver all translations. So its purely FE solution where you have to write all your translations during a .config phase. I have to be able to fetch translations from BE. I do not know if there is any existing solution for that or if angular-translate could also do that.

Comment: Not true, you can fetch json files with translations from the backend with angular-translate.

Comment: See staticFilesLoader section here: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the **angular-translate-loader-static-files** extension for [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). See the documentation [here](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading).

This together with proper configuration of `$translateProvider` will allow you to fetch json files with translations from the backend or even swap translations on demand - for example user changes language setting, controller reconfigures `$translateProvider`. Your job is done - everything will be fetched and updated automatically without a page reload.